# How to change date format using pipe filter for angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using dynamic report where I don't know the value of col value for each row but if the value is of date format then I want to convert it from Y-m-d to dd-mm-yyyy

**here is my code where I am printing a val for col**

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in list.data">                                 
   <td ng-repeat="val in row">{{val}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: you can use moment js (https://momentjs.com/) for this

Answer (score 0):

If `{{val}}` contains a valid date format, you can use the **[Angular `date` filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)** to format it as you want:

```
{{val | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}
```

Comment: But this filter is converting each value to date which I dont't want.